# eclipse won't start - no java virtual machine was found

Tags: eclipse, java

Eclipse was running fine yesterday (and has been since I installed it about a year ago). Now all the sudden I'm getting the following error on startup:

```
"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"
```

I have not changed anyhing Eclipse/Java related on my machine but a Windows update was applied to my machine yesterday, so maybe that has something to do with it (but I don't see anything that would affect Java). I've looked at all the other posts about adding something to your PATH or adding the -vm option to the Eclipse ini (couldn't get this to work) or copying the jre folder to eclipse\jre (this worked but doesn't seem like a good long term solution). So I'm really trying to figure out how to get things back to the "default" setup without messing stuff up.

I'm running `Windows 7, Eclipse Helios and Java 1.6.0_26.`

Comment: best and easy way to do this is to reinstall your java and set the path on eclipse

Comment: Nambari - Any reason why the JAVA_HOME variable would suddenly disappear? EDIT: just tried setting the JAVA_HOME env var and still get the error on eclipse startup.

Comment: @Nambari "Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable." [FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM)

Comment: Just set JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Two ways to work around this .

- **Recommended way** : In your `eclipse.ini` file make sure you are
  pointing -vm to your jdk installation. More on this [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example). Make sure to add `-vm` before the `-vmargs` section.
- Pass in the `vm` flag from command line. http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM

*Note* : Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Bizarre - I tried adding -vm in the eclipse.ini about 50 times yesterday and couldn't get it to work. Now all of the sudden it's working. Thanks for making me try it again. Follow-up: Any guess why it stopped working?? How was it working before adding -vm to the ini??

Comment: If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the system path variable. Most likely your PATH got screwed up after the update.

Comment: -vm needs to be the first entry in eclipse.ini file

Comment: I have the same problem. Where should I put eclipse.ini?

Comment: @Marjeta `eclipse.ini` is present in your eclipse installation folder.

Comment: Another tip, adding the "-vm" wasnt working for me when I was adding it at the end of the eclipse.ini file. Finally I added it to the top of the file and then it worked.

Comment: "-vm" worked when it is placed over the line "-vmargs". Refer http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3a_Windows_Example

Comment: Eclipse must have changed the ini file while updating itself. Worked fine before then would not start. Fixing the ini file solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: For me, this error appeared after updating Java.  Upon checking the ini file, it was pointing at the old version.  I updated the path to the new version and it worked.

Comment: Thank you . This is bizzarre. Eclipse shouldn't be un-openable just because JRE version has changed due to an upgrade.

Comment: i have this issue each time java updates and creates a new folder in the process. so each time i just update the eclipse.ini file so it points to the new folder. thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: I had this problem after a Java Update, Eclipse wouldn't start because eclipse.ini was pointing to the previous Java version. This is kind of dumb, no? I mean, why should the vm be hardcoded in eclipse.ini?

Comment: **Open Eclipse.ini  file present in the root folder of eclipse** and write ```-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre-<your version of jre>\bin``` and your work is done.
Do ensure the type of OS architecture you are using. 86x or 64
for 86 -> ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre-<your version of jre>\bin```

and for 64  -> ```C:\Program Files\Java\jre-<your version of jre>\bin```

Comment: everything after -vmargs will be passed to the JVM, so the two lines with -vm and the actual (dll) path needs to be inserted before that section. Modified the answer with that.

Comment: In my macOS environment, I had to set the "-vm" parameter in both Eclipse.ini and in info.plist (both found inside Eclipse.app).

Comment: On Fedora 32, the ini file is located here: `/etc/eclipse.ini`

Answer (score 16):

Make sure both the Java version and Eclipse are belongs to same architecture.So install 64 bit java for 64 bit eclipse.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Specifying a VM or PATH does not seem necessary, only a hassle when upgrading.

Answer (score 14):

**eclipse.ini:**

```
--launcher.defaultAction  
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
256M  
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize<br/>
256m  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
-showsplash  
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll<br/>
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
256m  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
-vmargs  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

That worked for me. It doesnt have to be on the beginning, but surely it cant be at the end of the file.

Comment: The vm flag wanted the jvm.dll in place of javaw.exe. Thanks!

Comment: I tried, both, javaw.exe and jvm.dll; both are 32-bit and still have that pop-up

Answer (score 12):

In my case i had few things missing. I didnt install JDK and JRE of 64 bit while eclipse was of 64 bit version. Once done and JDK\bin path was set in PATH variable eclipse worked fine :)

Comment: duh! i had installed 32 bit java and 64 bit eclipse. my face is red.

Answer (score 8):

Open `eclipse.ini` file besides `eclipse.exe`

paste

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll 
 //find it if you are having another JDK version.
```

on first line. **And you are good to go.**

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem after updating java.
Then I paste

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
```

to show the path of `javaw.exe` in `eclipse.ini` file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yup, upvoted your answer. Also make sure to keep it at the top of the ini!

Answer (score 4):

After setting Java Path, if you are not able to open your eclipse do below steps:

1. Go to your Eclipse Folder where you have extracted your eclipse.

[image]

2. Open Eclipse file in notepad (by default it will open on notepad)

Enter two lines

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/bin/javaw.exe
```

**jdk-11.0.2 ,It should be your Java Version, which you will get by the above location.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I my case it was a program i've install that had destroyed the PATH env variable.

so check your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

First

check if you have both java 32 and 64 bit install then

Setting Path on Windows

Windows 8

Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen

Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel

Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced

Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.

In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH, Or simply make sure that the variable name is in ALL CAPS

If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.

Close the window.

Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Answer (score 1):

***Via Puppet ATG installation Centos.***

**ERROR:**

No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH

**SOLUTION:**

Declear variable **:**

**$java_home="/opt/oracle/product/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin"**

Add This **"{$java_home}"** Java Exec

```
require common, java
Exec {
    path => [ "${java_home}", "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "${temp_directory}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Centos 7** I fixed this problem (after a big `yum upgrade`) by changing my setting for `vm` in:

`~/eclipse/java-oxygen/eclipse/eclipse.ini`

to:

```
-vm
/etc/alternatives/jre/bin
```

(which will always point to the latest installed `java`)

Answer (score 1):

If Eclipse isn't finding your JRE/JDK or finding the wrong version, add the following two lines to the beginning of your ***eclipse.ini*** file:

```
-vm
[your-path-to-java-executable]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing 32-bit version of Java, and then setting the path :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it happend to me right now. Go to Oracle site, and search for Java SDK. Make sure you use   the same architeture (x86, x64) of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This  happened to me also. And I found the javaw.exe in C:\Windows\System32 got deleted after the windows update. Copied one more time and Eclipse started all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chek os,eclipse,and java whether it is 32 or 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

you can also copy your JRE folder to eclipse directory and it will work corectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred on my machine due to Java version got updated(66 from 60). Pay special attention to it. As said above would like to add

In this file **eclipse.ini**, which is available where you have installed eclipse search for the line below **-vm** example
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_**66**\bin

now try to open this location, in case you are not able to open, that means there is some problem. In my case the version installed was jre1.8.0_**60** . So there was a small difference which may not noticeable(66 instead of 60). Update it you will be able to open.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue y'day, with PATH etc configured correctly.
It can be opened from command line,  just now working by a double click.

And it was working now, by just "**Run as administrator**" :)

Answer (score 0):

Some time this happens when your Java folder get updated.

Open Eclipse folder and search file eclipse.ini.
Open the eclipse.ini file and check whether jre version is same as jre available in your java folder.

I faced same problem when my jre got changed from jre1.8.0_101 to jre1.8.0_111.

**C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin
to
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the path was enclosed in quotation marks ("):

```
-vm 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin"
```

Removing them fixed the problem:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is **Include JDK's "bin" Directory in the PATH**

To edit the `PATH` environment variable in `Windows 7/8/10:`

1. Launch "Control Panel" ⇒ (Optional) System and Security ⇒ System ⇒ Click "Advanced system settings" on the left pane.
2. Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ Push "Environment Variables" button.
   Under "System Variables" (the bottom pane), scroll down to select "Path" ⇒ Click "Edit...".
3. Copy the JDK bin directory from JAVA folder and paste to "Edit..."

Answer (score 0):

you should change the jdk path in eclipse.ini here:

/Users/you_username/eclipse/jee-photon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini

after you should restart eclipse :)