# why eclipse is prompting alert message to install jre1.6 although I have installed jre1.7?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am facing an issue while opening my eclipse (indigo) version. it is displaying following alert message

To open “Eclipse,” you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?

although I have jdk 1.7 already installed on my machine. this issue I am facing after upgrading my Mac OSX from 10.7.5 to 10.8.5. please suggest me some how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse won't start - no java virtual machine was found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426810/eclipse-wont-start-no-java-virtual-machine-was-found)

Comment: Can you update your ini file with post?