# No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, command-prompt, java-9

> A Java Run Time Environment(JRE) or Java development Kit (JDK) must be 
>   available 
>   in order to run eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the 
>   following locations: H:\Important Software\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe java.exe in
>   your current path

These are shown while I am trying to start eclipse. But some days ago I have worked with eclipse fine. and I have checked java path in my system and environment variable. All are okay. Hence eclipse does not starting. I have restarted my pc also.

One thing I have to mention that `javac` command did not work while I was trying to compile my java code from command promt. Then I used this command to set path that is `set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4`. After that `javac` command was working fine. But now this problem occurs. eclipse did not starting.

And the main problem is my system is finding the jdk/jre in H drive where I put eclipse IDE but not the jdk/jre. I don't understand what's happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you have a 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: JDK 8 was the last release with a "jre" directory. The error message you have highlighted suggests Eclipse is looking for javaw.exe with a file path than includes "jre". Hopefully Eclipse doesn't depend on that, otherwise it will need changes to work on JDK 9 and newer.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Java 9 is supported only since version Oxygen.1a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse won't start - no java virtual machine was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426810/eclipse-wont-start-no-java-virtual-machine-was-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to all set classpath

Follow this
In user Environment variable set

```
VariableName  variableValue
CLASSPATH     .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;
JAVA_HOME     jdkpath( example :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151)
JRE_HOME      %JAVA_HOME%\jre
```

And in system variable

Add path

```
path       %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

Now you can work in all IDEs

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse home and find this eclipse.ini file. Check if this file has vm settings in it.

If it has something like below change it to your java path or remove it if your JAVA_HOME env variable is set

-vm
H:\Important Software\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

For mac the setting for the jvm is in Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist for it is: /Users/"username"/eclipse/java-2021-06/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist

```
      <!-- To use a specific Java version (instead of the default) uncomment the following option and
            edit it to add a VM. Installed VMs can be found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
    -->
            <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```